# Фиксированный блок

Tags: javascript, css

Есть простая реализация, но дело в том что нужно чтобы блок начал фиксацию чуть раньше, не от верха окна браузера а допустим на 50px от него

```js
$(function() {
  var topPos = $('.floating').offset().top; //topPos - это значение от верха блока до окна браузера
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (top > topPos) $('.floating').addClass('fixed');
    else $('.floating').removeClass('fixed');
  });
});
```

```css
.floating {}

.fixed {
  max-width: 240px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="floating">Блок</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: `if( top > 50 )` ?

Comment: @Yuri ,да, спасибо, сделайте ответ, я отмечу как верный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужно в js добавить, и в css добавить... разницу в 50px.. иначе будут рывки

var top = $(document).scrollTop();

```js
$(function() {
  var topPos = $('.floating').offset().top; //topPos - это значение от верха блока до окна браузера
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop() + 50;
    if (top > topPos) $('.floating').addClass('fixed');
    else $('.floating').removeClass('fixed');
  });
});
```

```css
.floating {}

.fixed {
  max-width: 240px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="floating">Блок</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Comment: А может лучше `$('.floating').offset().top - 50` ?